# Wordpress editor hotkeys (Mac - Chrome)

Tags: wordpress, macos, editor, media, hotkeys

Wordpress have hotkeys which can be very useful when editing a page/post.

example:

[image: Wordpress Hotkeys]

However, when i try to use a hotkey (Alt-Shift-m) to insert image on a OSX, or any other hotkey for that matter, it returns a symbol instead of applying the hotkey.

any clue how to fix that ?

Comment: Works ok for me. Could it be browser specific? I tested in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks,using chrome on 10.9.2,, not working for me..

Comment: What if you disable all plugins and swap to a default theme?

Comment: tried on a different theme, on a different site without success..

Comment: didnt got the chance to try with the default theme though i think it's not the case..

Comment: I'm also running 10.9.2. You cannot be sure, the following disables the hotkeys: `add_action( 'wp_default_scripts' , function ($wp_scripts) { $wp_scripts->remove('jquery-hotkeys'); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer...

if you experiencing such behaviour, try checking if one of your chrome extensions is overwriting 
the hotkeys or conflict them. in my case it was **1Password.**